# How can I link input boxes to code in script editor?

Tags: html, sharepoint-2013, user-input

I have very little knowledge on coding, but my work wants to use a thermometer to gage some costs on our sharepoint site. I found a free thermometer online, and I can adjust the code to reflect the amounts, but I was hoping to add some input boxes so that I wouldn't have to go into the code every time, which I have inputted into a script editor web part. My issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to connect the input boxes to the code for the thermometer. I am hoping someone might know how, if it is even possible with the script I have. Please help!

My code is in the comments as it won't let me add it here for some reason.

Comment: Thermometer code:<div style="text-align:center;">

<a alt="Fundraising Thermometer">

<img border="0" src="http://www.coolfundraisingideas.net/thermometer/thermometer.php?currency=dollar&goal=100&raised=25&color=blue&size=large">

</a>

<p style="font-size:.8em; color:#999"></p>

</div>

Comment: Input code:

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3">

<tr>

<td>Goal:</td>

<td>&#36;</td>

<td><input type="text" name="goal" size="6" maxlength="8" align="right" value=""></td>

</tr>

<tr><td>Amount Recovered:</td>

<td>&#36;</td>

<td><input type="text" name="raised" size="6" maxlength="8" align="right" value=""></td>

</tr>

</table>

 

<input type="submit" name="createbtn" class="createbtn" value="Submit">

Comment: Hi Nicole, you can edit your original question and place your code in it rather than displaying it in the comments - see the response to this question on how to embed your code in your questions accordingly - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try following code:

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <a alt="Fundraising Thermometer">
        <img border="0" id="img"
            src="http://www.coolfundraisingideas.net/thermometer/thermometer.php?currency=dollar&goal=100&raised=25&color=blue&size=large">
    </a>
    <p style="font-size:.8em; color:#999">This is Thermometer:</p>
</div>

<table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="3">
    <tr>
        <td>Goal:</td>
        <td>&#36;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="goal" size="6" maxlength="8" align="right" id="goal"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Amount Recovered:</td>
        <td>&#36;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="raised" size="6" maxlength="8" align="right" id="raised"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br />

<input type="button" name="createbtn" value="Submit" id="createbtn">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#createbtn").click(function () {
            var imgsrc = $('#img').attr('src');
            var goal_v = $('#goal').val();
            var raised_v = $('#raised').val();

            let newimgsrc = SetUrlKeyValue('raised', raised_v, false, SetUrlKeyValue('goal', goal_v, false, imgsrc));

            $('#img').attr('src', newimgsrc);
            alert(newimgsrc);
        });

    });

</script>
```

Test on SP 2013:

[image]

BR

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your time! I am super grateful. I tried your code and nothing seems to happen. I am at a loss as to why it works on yours and not on mine.